# Do the trees follow Fibonacci series? How?

Tags: biology, plants

Does the number of leaves on a branch follow Fibonacci numbers from top to bottom? 
Or is there more to nature than I really see it.

This question came up after reading this article:

> Aidan Dwyer took a hike through the trees last winter and took notice of patterns in the mangle of branches. His studies into how they branch in very specific ways lead him to a central guiding formula, the Fibonacci sequence.

—[13-Year-Old Makes Solar Power Breakthrough by Harnessing the Fibonacci Sequence](http://inhabitat.com/13-year-old-makes-solar-power-breakthrough-by-harnessing-the-fibonacci-sequence/)

The kid in the above article states that he planted tiny solar panels in the form of a tree and it followed the Fibonacci series. But I really do not get the connection between the Fibonacci series and the tree structure as a whole.

Comment: http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/fibslide/jbfibslide.htm

Comment: There are many web-sites that repeat the assertion about Fibonacci numbers appearing in nature. IMO, however, it would be good to have a more educational reference that explains how simple rules that maximise the surface area of petals/branches/leaves lead to fibonacci sequences. I recall reading an excellent explanation, but have failed to find it.

Comment: Thank you for editing. I though it question was lost for the initial down votes until now.

Answer (score 8):

[Vi Hart](http://vihart.com/) ([Wikipedia biography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi_Hart)) has produce a three part series of videos describing this phenomenon, called [Doodling in Math: Spirals, Fibonacci, and Being a Plant](http://youtu.be/ahXIMUkSXX0).

It explores the nature of spirals, Fibonacci and the patterns seen in plants.

The [third part in the series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14-NdQwKz9w) describe how this phenomena can be explained with a simple model of growth hormone.

Now, this isn't a formal academic document, but Hart provides a [follow-up video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POKWkuwoihM) containing appropriate references. If the goal of a good Skeptics.SE answer is to popularise scientific results, while retaining rigour, Vi Hart achieves this goal better than I ever will, so I am happy to defer to these videos as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Head over to this web page :
[Fibonacci Numbers and Nature](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibnat.html)

Look at the 'Leaf arrangements' sections . You can clearly see that the leave arrangements and the turn of leaves both follow Fibonacci sequence and also note the section 'Always Fibonacci? ' You will find that Nature is too unpredictable to always follow Fibonacci number.